# Managing the behavior of the "Cancel" link in Rails' ActiveAdmin forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

A typical form produced by the ActiveAdmin DSL might look like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :content
    end
    f.actions
  end
  ...
end
```

The `f.actions` bit renders both a submit button and a cancel link. The problem is that the latter's target is always the index page. Instead, for a previously persisted record I would like to be taken back to the show page. As a possible workaround, `f.actions` could be replaced with:

```
f.actions do
  f.action :submit
  if resource.persisted?
    f.cancel_link({action: :show})
  else
    f.cancel_link
  end
end
```

This, however, seems verbose and clunky. Am I missing some more idiomatic trick to accomplish the same?

Comment: It will be great to have this as default behaviour for active admin